Gnuplot: set aspect ratio of x & y axes in 3D plot
I'm creating a 3D plot via splot in gnuplot 6.0 and want to manually set the scaling (/aspect ratio) of all three axes.
There are a few related commands, but none of them quite does it:

The scale of the z axis can be set using the fourth argument of the set view command. This is exactly what I want, but the command works only for the z axis. This is why the title says 'x & y', there needs to be some other way to scale those two.

For a 2D plot, you can set the aspect ratio of the x and y axes with set size ratio <r>, but this does not work in a 3D plot.
(You can also do set size <xscale>,<yscale> which works for a 2D plot, but for a 3D plot, it scales the final 2D projection on screen, not the axes.)

The only option for a 3D plot I can find that sets the scaling of x and y is set view equal xy (or set view equal xyz), which forces the axes to a 1:1(:1) aspect ratio. But I want to set an aspect ratio that's different from 1:1(:1).


(The only workaround I can think of is scaling the data itself, and then modifying the tick marks to compensate. But it feels like there has to be a better way.)

Example
Here is a simple line with two rectangular 'pulses', one in y and one in z direction. It's plotted with splot "data.csv" with lines without any further modifications:

This is what data.csv looks like:
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 3 0
2 3 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
4 0 3
5 0 3
5 0 0
6 0 0

What I want is something like this, where the x:y:z scaling is 5:1:1 (so one unit length on the x axis is displayed 5 times as long as one on the y or z axis, and y and z are scaled equally).

(This was produced via the above workaround by fixing the scaling of the axes via set view equal xyz and then just scaling the data via splot "data.csv" using ($1*5):2:3 with lines. But now, of course the tics would display wrong values, so I turned them off.)

What are typical data ranges in x,y,z and what are the desired visual ratios of x,y,z? What are the viewing angles or is it on an interactive terminal? Could you please show an illustration what you have and how you want it to look like?

Hi, thanks for taking a look! I've added an example to the question, I hope it helps. (The images are just screenshots from an interactive terminal (with the viewing angle also set interactively), but my question applies the same to non-interactive terminals.)

Thanks for providing a sketch. This made it much easier to understand.

Here is a suggestion which might help you a little further.
I guess the "secret" is the following lines, which is basically a mapping to different coordinates (check help nonlinear).
set view equal xyz
Rx = 5.0
set nonlinear x via x*Rx inverse x/Rx

However, there are a few more things:

set view 60,30, 3,3 : scale x and z by factor 3 to fill the canvas with the graph
e.g. set xtics 1 scale 4.0 offset -1.0,-0.5 to adjust the length of the xtics and the offset of the xticlabels. Similar for ytics and ztics

What is not yet clear to me, e.g. in case you want to set a ratio x:y:z of 5:1:2

why set nonlinear z via z*Rz inverse z/Rz shifts the graph outside the canvas and how to shift it back?

Script:
### set visually different xyz ratio than 1:1:1
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 3 0
2 3 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
4 0 3
5 0 3
5 0 0
6 0 0
EOD

set view equal xyz
set view 60,30, 3,3
Rx = 5.0
Ry = 1.0
Rz = 1.0
set nonlinear x via x*Rx inverse x/Rx
set nonlinear y via y*Ry inverse y/Ry
# set nonlinear z via z*Rz inverse z/Rz   # this will lead to a shift of the graph

unset key
set tics out
set xtics 1 scale 4.0 offset -1.0,-0.5
set mxtics Rx
set yrange[-1:4]
set ytics 1 scale 0.333 offset -2.0, 0.5
set ztics 1 scale 1.0
set xyplane relative 0
set grid x,mx,y,z vertical
set border 1+2+4+8+16+32+64+256+512

splot $Data u 1:2:3 w l lw 2 lc "red"
### end of script

Result:


That solves it! Thank you so much, also for putting the extra work in to style everything nicely, instead of just solving the problem.
I also get the weird offset when using set nonlinear z ..., I assume it's a bug? The offset doesn't even depend on Rz. It's possible to shift the plot back into view using something like set origin 0,0.4.

@Fii you're welcome! I guess the offset/shift is not a bug but more a lack of our understanding how it is actually scaled. I was trying something with set margins or set bmargin, but you are right, I didn't think of set origin. Not sure yet, how you would calculate the right origin which might depend on z-scaling and maybe viewing angle.
